# Why are linear combinations of independent standard normal random variables also normally distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-writing

My professor has given a list of questions that **will not** be appearing on my test, with this being one of them. I still feel this is extremely important to understand.

How can I prove the following

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, standard normal random variables, then the
>   linear combination $aX+bY,\;\forall a,b>0$ is also
>   normally distributed.

---

If I am not mistaken, I believe I can find the distribution of the linear combination

> If we let $Z=aX+bY$, knowing $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$, we can find the expectation and variance as
>   $$\mathbb{E}(Z)=\mathbb{E}(aX+bY)=a\mathbb{E}(X)+b\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$$
>   $$Var(Z)=Var(aX+bY)=a^2Var(X)+b^2Var(Y)=a^2+b^2$$
>   $$$$
>   Thus, $Z \sim N(0,a^2+b^2)$.

I just don't think this proves that linear combination is normally distributed. I tried looking in some reference books that my professor reserved at the library, but they all just state the fact and I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: **Disclaimer**: You will most likely waste time better invested in learning for your test if you keep reading now.

With that out of the way, a really nice geometric argument using the rotation invariance of the joint density function of two independent random variables is found [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Eisenberg12-0825740.pdf). (*Why Is the Sum of Independent Normal Random Variables Normal?* B. Eisenberg and R. Sullivan, The Mathematical Magazine, Vol. 81, No. 5, December 2008)

Comment: @binkyhorse That is the most elegant proof of this I've seen!

Answer (score 3):

The most direct way is to [look at the characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Proof_using_characteristic_functions).

The characteristic function of an r.v. characterizes its probability distribution completely. If you can show that the characteristic function of the linear combination is that of a normal r.v., you are done.

Comment: The questions my professor posted were "highly considered for the test" and we have never used characteristic functions in my course. So I don't think he would have expected us to use them to prove it on the test. Is there a different way to prove it without the use of them?

Comment: You *can* look at the CDF of the linear combination directly, but it's a little more involved. This is one the same page in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Geometric_proof

Comment: @MathIsFun it is also possible to go through the same proof using [moment generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) rather than characteristic functions.  Perhaps these are more familiar.

Comment: Haven't seen those either. I don't exactly know what is expected since we aren't getting any solutions. I think the geometric case listed above makes some sense but I haven't done change of coordinates on integrals in about 4 years so maybe I'm too rusty in that regard to full grasp the proof.

Comment: I would just take the time to read up on the characteristic function. It is an indispensable tool in probability.