# Conditional Expectation given the correlation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm taking an econometrics course and have been stumped by a seemingly easy question regarding conditional expectation.
We know that $E(X_1)=E(X_2)=0, Var(X_1)=Var(X_2)=1, Corr(X_1,X_2)=-0.35$

I am trying to find $E(X_2|X_1)$ in terms of $X_1$ which apparently is:
$E(X_2|X_1)=\rho_{12}X_1$

But I struggle to see how you can make that conclusion.

So far I know that $cov(X_1,X_2)=E((X_1-0)(X_2-0))=E(X_1X_2)=-0.35$

But I'm stumped from this point.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation  This may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is a general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3960305/215011) concerning **bivariate normal** random variables:

If $X$ and $Y$ have bivariate normal distribution with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ respectively, and variances $\sigma^2_1$ and $\sigma^2_2$ respectively, and correlation $\rho$, then:

$$E(X\mid Y) = \mu_1 + \rho\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(Y-\mu_2)$$

and

$$\operatorname{Var}(X\mid Y)=\sigma_1^2(1-\rho^2).$$

Comment: Aha! I do remember that from deriving conditional normal distributions in probability.
Thanks for your help!