# Is the vector of affine transformed independent normal distributions jointly normal?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random variables.

I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $(X,Y)$ is jointly normal.

But in general case, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, $(X,Y)$ is not necessary jointly normal.

I wonder if there is a vector of affine-transformed random vectors, for example

$$Z_1 = a_1X+b_1Y$$

$$Z_2 = a_2X +b_2Y$$

$Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are surely normal, and also dependent.

Is $(Z_1, Z_2)$ jointly normal? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: In the second half of your question (where you define $Z_1$ and $Z_2$), are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be independent?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are linear combinations of independent normal random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the [equivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions) of "$(Z_1, Z_2)$ is jointly normal" is

> $c_1 Z_1 + c_2 Z_2$ is normal for any choice of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

In your case, $c_1 Z_1 + c_2 Z_2$ can be rewritten in the form $c'_1 X + c'_2 Y$. Then using the fact that a [linear combination of *independent* normal random variables is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961765/why-are-linear-combinations-of-independent-standard-normal-random-variables-also), you can conclude that $c_1 Z_1 + c_2 Z_2$ is normal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.